# Search Database for strings

Tags: php, mysql

Am I going about this the right way? I've got 4 input areas which all revolve around filtering for a DB search and just a little confused as to how to do this correctly. What I've got:

```
$e_s=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['var_specs']);
$ven=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vender']);
$xtp=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['xtype']);
$sar=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sarea']);
if(strlen($e_s) > 1){
    if ($e_s && $Area=="vars"){
        $AreaSearch = "db_vars";
        $TypeResults = "vars";
        $TypeUrl = "vars";
        $search = $e_s;
    }
    // IF VENDER
    if($ven=="ALL" || $ven==""){
        $vender_search="%";
    }
    else {
        $vender_search="%".$ven."%";
    }
    // IF TYPE
    if($xtp=="ALL"){
        $xtype_search="%";
    }
    else {
        $xtype_search="%".$xtp."%";
    }
    // IF AREA
    if($sar=="ALL"){
        $sarea_search="%";
    }
    else {
        $sarea_search="%".$sar."%";
    }

    // RUN QUERY
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$AreaSearch." WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%' AND vender LIKE ".$vender_search." AND xtype LIKE ".$xtype_search." AND sarea LIKE ".$sarea_search);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better method is this:

```
$parameters = array();

if($ven != "ALL" && $ven != "") {
    $parameters[] = "vender LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($ven) . "%'";
}
if ($xtp ...) {
   $parameters[] = ...
}
if ($sar ...) {
etc...

if (count($parameters > 0) {
   $where_clause = implode(' AND ', $parameters);
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE $where_clause";
   $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   ...
} else {
   die("NO search parameters entered");
}
```

Note the call to mysql_real_escape_string() above. This will escape any SQL metacharacters in the user-provided text and prevent SQL injection attacks. Never ever directly insert user-provided data into a database query, even if you're the only person who'd ever use the system.

Comment: Note: this does not protect you against a very simple DOS attack. You should check for a minimum character length and cache the result of this query.